# Netflix kind of carousel ui button recreating divs using getComputedStyle css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to recreate netflix kind of carousel ui using this wds tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yq4BeRtUHbk) for movie cast details using Reactjs and running through a problem.

I am fetching data from moviedb database and trying to achieve netflix like carousel effect.
the problem is when i click button for changing the slider index using getComputedStyle in css,
I get entire div recreated again several times.

I Fetch the data in the MovieDetails component and pass it to MovieDetailsPage component

```
export default function MovieDetails() {

const [MovieDetail, setMovieDetail] = useState([])
const [CastDetails, setCastDetails] = useState([])

const { id } = useParams();

const API_Key = '4ee812b6fb59e5f8fc44beff6b8647ed';


console.log('this is id', id);


useEffect(() => {

    getDetail();
    getCastDetails();

    console.log('main');

}, [id])

const getDetail = useCallback(() => {

    fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${id}?api_key=${API_Key}&language=en-US`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data, 'data');
            setMovieDetail(data)
        })

}, [id])

const getCastDetails = useCallback(() => {

    fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${id}/credits?api_key=${API_Key}&language=en- 
    US`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            setCastDetails(data.cast)
        }
        )

        console.log('get cast details rendered');

}, [id])

useEffect(() => {

    console.log(MovieDetail, 'Moviedetils')

}, [MovieDetail])


return (

    <div>
        <MoviesDetailsPage {...MovieDetail} CastDetails={CastDetails} API_Key={API_Key} />
    </div>


)
}
```

**MovieDetailsPage.jsx**

```
export default function MoviesDetailsPage({ id, poster_path, backdrop_path, API_Key, 
 CastDetails }) {

const API_image = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/';


document.addEventListener('click', e => {
   e.preventDefault();
   let handle;
   if(e.target.matches(".handle")){
    handle = e.target
   }else{
    handle = e.target.closest(".handle")
   }
   
   if(handle != null) onHandleClick(handle)
   
})

function onHandleClick(handle){
    const slider = handle.closest(".MovieCastContainer").querySelector(".slider")
    console.log(slider, 'sliderindex')
    
    const sliderIndex = parseInt(getComputedStyle(slider).getPropertyValue("--slider-index"))

    if(handle.classList.contains("left-handle")){
        slider.style.setProperty("--slider-index", sliderIndex - 1)
    }

    if(handle.classList.contains("right-handle")){
        slider.style.setProperty("--slider-index", sliderIndex + 1)
    }


}

const castInfo = CastDetails && CastDetails.map(data => <img src={API_image+data.profile_path} 
alt={data.name}   />)


console.log(CastDetails, 'Castdetails')

return (
    <div className="MovieDetailsPageCont">

        <div className='MovieDetailsContainer'>
            <div className="headerImg"><img src={API_image + backdrop_path} 
    alt='backdrop_path' style={{ width: '100%', borderRadius: '10px' }} /></div>
            <div className="movieid">{id}</div>
        </div>

        <div className='MovieCastContainer'>

            <button className="handle left-handle">
            <div className="text">&#8249;</div>    
            </button>

            <div className='slider'>

                {
                    castInfo ? castInfo : '...Loading'
                }

            </div>

            <button className="handle right-handle">
                <div className="text">&#8250;</div>
            </button>

        </div>

    </div>
)
 }
```

My css page where change the slider index to transfrom to next set of values

```
*, *::after, *::before{
box-sizing: border-box;
   }

:root{
--slider-padding: 5rem;
}

    .MovieCastContainer{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
overflow: hidden;

}

.slider{
--slider-index: 0; 
display: flex;
flex-grow: 1;
margin: 0 .25rem;
transform: translateX(calc(var(--slider-index) * -100%));
transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
   }

.slider > img {
flex: 0 0 25%;
max-width: 25%;
aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
padding: .25rem;
border-radius: 1rem;
overflow: hidden;
  }

.handle{
border: none;
border-radius: 1rem;
flex-grow: 0;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
z-index: 10;
margin: .25rem 0;
padding: 0 .5rem;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 5rem;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
color: white;
line-height: 0;
transition: font-size 150ms ease-in-out;

}

.left-handle{
border-top-left-radius: 0;
border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.right-handle{
border-top-right-radius: 0;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.handle:hover,
.handle:focus {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);

}


 .handle:hover .text,
 .handle:focus .text{
transform: scale(1.2)
}
```

Everytime I click next button in ui the I get this

[image]

please if you can help out with this any help would be appreciated.